# overpass turbo: query returns empty set

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm using this statement on https://overpass-turbo.eu/:

```
[timeout:900];
area[name="Germany"][admin_level=2][boundary=administrative]->.myarea;
rel(area.myarea)[admin_level=4][boundary=administrative];
out geom;
```

Why is this returning an empty dataset? First I select the area of germany, then I select all relations which represent the state boundaries. Like this one:
http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/62761#map=8/51.440/7.660

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the country name is tagged as "Deutschland" rather than "Germany", you need to adjust the .myarea part of your query:

```
[timeout:900];
area[name="Deutschland"][admin_level=2][boundary=administrative]->.myarea;
rel(area.myarea)[admin_level=4][boundary=administrative];
out geom;
```

In any case, I would recommend the following faster approach based on tagging schema:

```
rel[boundary=administrative]["ISO3166-2"~"^DE-"][admin_level=4];
out geom;
```

Comment: thanks, that works! which resource do you use to find out that I need to put "Deutschland" instead of germany?

Comment: See the [relation for Germany](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/51477). Name is always the local name.

Comment: but how do you get to the page behind that link in the first place? and: I don't see anything like "local_name"? I searched for "local" with ctrl + f

Comment: Just search for Germany at https://www.openstreetmap.org or http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/. And there is no local_name key for this relation, this doesn't really make sense.

Comment: oops I thought you were referring to some variable but you meant that the language of the name tag is always the native language of the country, okay gotcha. I followed your link and scrolled down to the "name" (not int_name or whatever) of that relation and I can see that it's written in german. thanks!